# Function pattern match depending on data argument

Tags: haskell

First of: sorry for the ambigous question title...
Second: I am a *complete* beginner...

I have a very simple data type called Task. A Task had a price, an amount and a unit. The unit can be days or hours.

I want to calculate the total amount and total price for a list of Tasks. For the price there is no issue, I multiply each price with the amount for the given task and it adds up. But for the amount I am stuck.

I cannot easely fold a list of hours and days. Say I have a task with 1 hour and one with 1 day, both of them have an amount of 1, but the total should be in one unit. I chose 'hour' as the base unit.

So to recap, this is my type:

```
-- data --

-- the task is parsed from json, but I would like the `unit` type to be
-- custom like `Hour | Day` instead of String. But that is an aeson issue?
data Task = {
  amount :: Double,
  price :: Double,
  unit :: String
}

-- functions --

taskPrice :: Task -> Double
taskPrice t = fromIntegral (price t) * amount t

calcPrice :: [Task] -> Double
calcPrice [] = 0
calcPrice [x] = taskPrice x
calcPrice (x:xs) = foldl (\acc x -> acc + (taskPrice x)) (taskPrice x) xs

-- this version will add days and hours like they are equal...
calcInvoiceHours :: [Task] -> Double
calcInvoiceHours [] = 0
calcInvoiceHours [x] = amount x
calcInvoiceHours (x:xs) = foldl (\acc x -> acc + (amount x)) (amount x) xs
```

Every Task *knows* it's own type, but a switch case inside the pattern matching is not the way to go I guess... In some naive pseudo code I would write:

```
calcInvoiceHours :: [Task] -> Double
calcInvoiceHours [] = 0
calcInvoiceHours [x -> unit x === Hour] = amount x
calcInvoiceHours [x -> unit x === Day] = (amount x) * 8 -- work 8 hours a day
calcInvoiceHours (x:xs) = foldl (\acc x -> acc + (amount x)) (amount x)
```

I *know* this is wrong, but I do not know how to do it. I might be running before I can walk here, but it seems like such a simple task (no pun intended).

Thanks!

**== UPDATE ==**

I found a way! But if this is not the good way, I would be glad to hear how I can improve! Plus I am still searching to parse the strings 'hours' and 'days' to a concrete custome type Hour | Day from json.

```
taskHours :: Task -> Double
taskHours (Task _ amount _ unit)
  | unit == "hours" = amount
  | otherwise = amount * 8

calcInvoiceHours :: [Task] -> Double
calcInvoiceHours [] = 0
calcInvoiceHours [x] = taskHours x
calcInvoiceHours (x:xs) = foldl (\acc x -> acc + (taskHours x)) (taskHours x) xs
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [sum types](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/sum-types)?

Comment: No, I am readying the documentation right now, thank you! I could make it work with the update above and also with the suggestion below.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review if **a)** the code works **and b)** the code isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need an explicit fold here. You just need a combination of `map` and `sum`.

```
inHours :: Task -> Double
inHours (Task amt _ "hours") = amt
inHours (Task amt _ "days") = 8 * amt

taskPrice :: Task -> Double
taskPrice t = (price t) * (inHours t)

calcPrice :: [Task] -> Double
calcPrice = sum . (map taskPrice)

calcInvoiceHours :: [Task] -> Double
calcInvoiceHours = sum . (map inHours)
```

Comment: The braces on the right hand side of your functions are unnecessary, btw. E.g., `taskPrice t = price t * inHours t`

Comment: I tend to overuse parentheses, mostly out of habit from when I couldn't remember exactly how currying and function application interacted with infix operators.

Answer (score 1):

You've left the treatment of *time* as a largely implicit part of your data model. I would model timespans as a self-contained abstract data type, with functions to calculate new timespans and to project various components of the timespan. This allows you to perform calculations in a canonical unit of your choice (I've chosen "ticks") in a manner that is opaque to code which uses the `TimeSpan` type.

```
-- Make the type abstract, so users can't directly manipulate ticks,
-- by keeping the TimeSpan constructor private to this module
newtype TimeSpan = TimeSpan Integer

-- you could pack these two into a Monoid instance if you like, or use GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving and get it without writing any code
zero :: TimeSpan
zero = TimeSpan 0
plus :: TimeSpan -> TimeSpan -> TimeSpan
plus (TimeSpan x) (TimeSpan y) = TimeSpan (x + y)

ticksPerHour :: Fractional a => a
ticksPerHour = 10000 * 1000 * 60 * 60  -- 10,000 ticks per millisecond

fromHours :: Float -> TimeSpan
fromHours = TimeSpan . hoursToTicks
    where hoursToTicks x = round (x * ticksPerHour)

toHours :: TimeSpan -> Float
toHours (TimeSpan x) = ticksToHours x
    where ticksToHours x = fromIntegral x / ticksPerHour

-- similar functions to measure the timespan in days, etc
```

This is just how you'd do it in an object-oriented language. [C#'s `TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `struct` (don't get me started on how bad C# structs are at data abstraction) which internally counts a *private* number of ticks, with public methods to convert a `TimeSpan` into various other measuring schemes such as hours or days. It's also more-or-less [what you'll find in Haskell's `Data.Time.Clock`](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/time-1.6.0.1/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:DiffTime) module.

Now you can use the abstract `TimeSpan` type directly in your code, delegating to your `TimeSpan` library to do the adding and subtracting in a units-independent manner.

```
data Task = Task {
    taskLength :: TimeSpan,
    taskPrice :: Money  -- omitted: a similar treatment to build an abstract Money type
}

totalTime :: [Task] -> TimeSpan
totalTime = foldl' plus zero . map taskLength

totalTimeHours :: [Task] -> Float
totalTimeHours = toHours . totalTime
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a bit much for me to grasp at the time, but I will keep it in mind while growing in the Haskell mindset/syntax